# error duirng loading "xlsx" library in R

Tags: r, package

I got the following errors after installing and require the xlsx library in R:

```
> install.packages("xlsx")
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/xlsx_0.5.5.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 395421 bytes (386 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 386 Kb
> require(xlsx)
Loading required package: xlsx
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'xlsx', details:
  call: .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook")
  error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
```

Tried and hunted around and can't figure out the problem. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: The `xlsx` package is written in Java. Do you have the Java runtime installed?

Comment: Yes, I even have reinstall the latest Java version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xlsx package` doesn't support the latest `Mac R version 3.01 & 3.02` but it works well under R 3.0. Use `gdata::read.xls` is recommended if so.